# Cannot implicitly convert string - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building very basic BMI Calculator in C# and Win Forms using VS 2012, also I'm quite new to C#. I'm followed some examples and this code should work, but when run code, I'm getting those errors.

```
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to 'string'  c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\bmi_calc\bmi_calc\Form1.cs  44  31  bmi_calc
Error   5   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to 'string'  c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\bmi_calc\bmi_calc\Form1.cs  45  31  bmi_calc
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'   c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\bmi_calc\bmi_calc\Form1.cs  39  25  bmi_calc
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'double.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments  c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\bmi_calc\bmi_calc\Form1.cs  44  17  bmi_calc
Error   4   The best overloaded method match for 'double.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments  c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\bmi_calc\bmi_calc\Form1.cs  45  17  bmi_calc
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bmi_calc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double v;
        double t;
        double r;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtTezina.Clear(); //Btn that resets height and weight field values.
            txtVisina.Clear();
            txtBmiRez = "";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            v = Double.Parse (txtVisina);
            t = Double.Parse (txtTezina);

            r = t / (v * v);

            txtBmiRez.Text = String.Format("{0:f}", r);

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit(); // Close app
        }

    }
}
```

If someone could explain me this, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: you should use the text property. if coming from vb6/vba, theres no concept of the implicit text property.

Comment: `v = Double.Parse (txtVisina.Text);` `t = Double.Parse (txtTezina.Text);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `txtVisina` and `txtTezina` are `TextBox` objects, not the strings that are contained within them. You need to use the `.Text` property coming off those objects to access the string value within the user interface.

For example:

```
v = Double.Parse (txtVisina.Text);
t = Double.Parse (txtTezina.Text);
```

and:

```
txtBmiRez.Text = "";
```

Funnily enough, your second usage of `txtBmiRez` is actually correct.

When it comes to parsing doubles (or any object from a string), it's also recommended to handle any potential errors with that which can be done with `TryParse`. `Parse` would throw an exception if the strings were not valid numbers whereas `TryParse` would return `false`. For example changing your Click method to something like this is advantageous and would reduce any potential for crashing:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Double.TryParse (txtVisina.Text, out v) &&
         Double.TryParse (txtTezina.Text, out t)) {
        r = t / (v * v);
        txtBmiRez.Text = String.Format("{0:f}", r);
    } else {
        // Handle failure to parse
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to parse text to number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm accepted your answer as a correct, and it runs with no errors, but always when try calculate  values I'm getting 0.00 result, it is pretty wierd, I must check my math form :D  however thank you a lot !

Comment: @GoranStojanovic No problem - remember you can debug to ensure that the values are correct when you calculate `r`. It could be your string format. You could always try `txtBmiRez.Text = r.ToString("F2");`

Answer (score 2):

The variables `txtVisina` and `txtTezina` are `TextBoxes` but you are trying to use them as strings. All you need to use is their `Text` property, i.e.

```
v = Double.Parse (txtVisina.Text);
t = Double.Parse (txtTezina.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `Text` property of a `TextBox` to get its text. You're trying to cast the text box itself.

For example, instead of

```
v = Double.Parse (txtVisina);
```

the following is correct:

```
v = Double.Parse (txtVisina.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Textbox.Text property to get the value entered in to the text box, for example

```
string enteredValue = textbox1.Text;
```

Easy mistake to make when you're starting out with WinForms.  I did it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

for the Errors 3 and 5 you must use .Text property for the TextBoxes.

To assign any string to a textbox you must use following syntax:

textboxid.Text=""; 
and if you want to assign any non string value to it then use:.ToString() function to convert a variable to string before assigning it to textbox.
eg 
int i=10;
Textbox1.Text=i.ToString();